# No rows being returned from MySQL query using PHP while manually running query returns rows

Tags: php, mysql, json, phpmyadmin

I am using jquery ajax to call up a PHP page simple API that returns JSON.
here is the code for that

```
<?php 


$response['is_error'] = 'no';
$user = $_POST['user'];
$date = $_POST['date'];

$sql = "select * from locations where user_id='$user' and DATE(timestamp) = '$date'";
$locations = $conn->query($sql) or $response['is_error'] = 'yes';
$response['num_rows'] = $locations->num_rows;

$locations = $locations->fetch_assoc(); 

$response['locations'] = $locations;
$response['date'] = $date;

if($response['is_error'] == 'yes'){
    $response['status'] = "failed";
    $response['error'] = $conn->error;
}else{
    $response['status'] = "ok";
}

$response['sql']=$sql;

echo json_encode($response);
```

When executed this script returns the following JSON

```
{"is_error":"no","num_rows":0,"locations":null,"date":"2019-07-30","status":"ok","sql":"select * from locations where user_id='0123456789' and DATE(timestamp) = '2019-07-30'"}
```

Here is the parsed version for the sake of viewing

```
date: "2019-07-30"
is_error: "no"
locations: null
num_rows: 0
sql: "select * from locations where user_id='0123456789' and DATE(timestamp) = '2019-07-30'"
status: "ok"
```

however, if I copy-paste the SQL echoed in JSON in the PHPMyAdmin page SQL it returns a row which was indeed intended it's just weird that it does not return anything while executing the same query using PHP in with the script.

here is an attached screenshot of the PHPMyAdmin query output

[image]

Running `print_r($conn)` echos following output

```
mysqli Object
(
    [affected_rows] => 1
    [client_info] => 5.6.30
    [client_version] => 50630
    [connect_errno] => 0
    [connect_error] => 
    [errno] => 0
    [error] => 
    [error_list] => Array
        (
        )

    [field_count] => 1
    [host_info] => Localhost via UNIX socket
    [info] => 
    [insert_id] => 0
    [server_info] => 5.6.44-cll-lve
    [server_version] => 50644
    [stat] => Uptime: 94095  Threads: 23  Questions: 77085244  Slow queries: 625  Opens: 814448  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 5000  Queries per second avg: 819.227
    [sqlstate] => 00000
    [protocol_version] => 10
    [thread_id] => 1035427
    [warning_count] => 0
)
```

Comment: Wild guess... are you sure to be connected to the right database with your application?

Comment: hack yeah there is only one database on the server.

Comment: And you should use prepared statements. Right now you're wide open to sql injection.

Comment: all inputs such as ` $_POST['user'];` are filtered for XSS and SQL Injection through a middleware right before passing the data to the file I have posted above.

Comment: Please check to run this code `echo '<pre>'; print_r($conn); echo '</pre>';`.

Comment: You should still use prepared statements since there actually are injection methods that can bypass a middleware. Just as a heads up.

Comment: sure things @LLJ97 thanks for letting me know that, I thought mysqli_real_escape_string was secure enough.

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: the output for print_r($conn); has been added to the question through an edit @BhavinThummar

Comment: @RishabhGusain can you check result for only this query `select * from locations` in your PHP script? Do you fetch the results or not?

Comment: @BhavinThummar doing `select * from locations` returns 5442 rows in both environment as expected

Comment: @RishabhGusain. Then please try this query `select * from locations where user_id='$user' ` and check.

Comment: 95 rows returned for the particular user @BhavinThummar

Comment: Please write timestamp field wrap by the "`". because it is the reserved keyword I think the issue may be solved if this is the problem.

Comment: check this screenshot for above comment http://prntscr.com/olx29v

Comment: @RishabhGusain do you have solved the issue or not?

Comment: @BhavinThummar No I haven't solved the issue yet it is confirmed that the issue is with Date comparison against timestamp field. I added back ticks "`" to the application in the query as `select * from locations where user_id='$user' and DATE(`timestamp`) = '$date'` with no luck

Comment: @RishabhGusain I have created same example at my end for timestamp date. Code file: http://prntscr.com/omch5x, database: http://prntscr.com/omchy7, output: http://prntscr.com/omcia1 that means my php script work for DATE function of mysqli. so can you told me your PHP version and mysql version?

Answer (score -2):

I think the user_id which is starting with 0 is creating a problem. Can you change the data type of the user_id column and make it as varchar and then try or else remove 0 from your query and also the table row and then check. It should work.

Comment: user_id is already varchar(12) and changing the user without any 0 didn't help either

Answer (score -2):

```
if (isset($_POST["adds"])) {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $db = "loc";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $response['is_error'] = 'no';
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $sql = "select * from location where user_id='$user' and DATE(timestamp) = '$date'";
    $locations = $conn->query($sql) or $response['is_error'] = 'yes';
    $response['num_rows'] = $locations->num_rows;

    $locations = $locations->fetch_assoc();
    $response['locations'] = $locations;
    $response['date'] = $date;
    if ($response['is_error'] == 'yes') {
        $response['status'] = "failed";
        $response['error'] = $conn->error;
    } else {
        $response['status'] = "ok";
    }
    $response['sql'] = $sql;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
`<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="user"><br>
        <input type="text" name="date"> <br>
        <input type="submit" name="adds">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The output of this script should be pure JSON else the application will crash in the frontend while parsing JSON. Do you have any idea what API means?